# write sql from multiple checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I researched a lot and found some solution ,probably not a convincing solution for me.Hence i am posting this question,Please help me

I Have A checkbox with same name and different values like

1.cate.php

`<form action="mobile-phones-category.php" method="post">`

`<input type="checkbox" value="samsung" name="mobile[]"> sams`

`<input type="checkbox" value="nokia" name="mobile[]"> nolkia`

`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">`

`</form>`

2.) mobile-phones-category.php

I retrieve the values of check box on submit[array format] and want to search from db..I am using normal mysql_query(not pdos)

`$search=$_POST["mobile"];
$search_string = implode(', ', $search);
echo $search_string`;

Here i Get something like Nokia,Sams

Next I write a single sql query
`include('connection.php');`

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename where titles like '%$search_string%' ") or die(mysql_error());`

What is happening is that only one value in the array is searched and not all the values in array..What changes should i Make so that all the array element should get searched

Thanks and regards

Comment: What are you trying to search for? `Nokia`, `Sams` or `Nokia,Sams`?

Comment: All `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) *(no longer supported/maintained)* and will be [**removed**](http://j.mp/11j2t6j) in the future. You should update your code using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure future functionality.

Comment: Also neither `PDO`, nor `mysqli` prevents [_sql injection_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) itself. Read up on [_prepared statements_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: @aman the thing is if i check two values and give submit , the values retrieved should include both nokia and sams

Comment: @PLB,@cryptic,Actually I used prepared statement in alomost all cases except this ....

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN` keyword in your query instead of `LIKE`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename where titles IN ($search_string)" ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Usage Example:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename where titles IN ('Nokia','Sams')" ) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will give you records with title Nokia & Sams from the table.

Comment: i am getting error "`Unknown column 'nokia' in 'where clause'`"

Comment: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM selling where titles IN ($search_string)" ) or die(mysql_error());`  where selling=table name

Comment: Also it is not taking the second value sams(if i select both)...Then also i m getting error`Unknown column 'nokia' in 'where clause'

Comment: You need to enclose the string in single quotes.Like in the example shown in the answer.

Comment: `$query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM selling where titles IN ('$search_string')" ) or die(mysql_error());` here  also i am able to get only nokia related value and not sams related value

Comment: ,or Can it be because of some case insensitivity in the database tables?

Comment: Can you show what is `$search_string` when it comes into the query

Comment: `$query_string` is not able to retrieve anything , ie the page is blank after query is executed along with error information which i mentioned

Comment: So try to `echo "SELECT * FROM selling where titles IN ('$search_string')";die;` before executing the query and trace the bug.

Comment: if i use `$query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM selling where titles IN ('nokia,'sans')" ) or die(mysql_error());` i am getting the right answer

Comment: you have to enclose each values in the `IN` condition in single quotes seperated with commas..Like this `SELECT * FROM selling where titles IN ('value1','value2','value3','value4','value5',)` and so on.Now try to format your values to the query and will solve the problem

Comment: ,its taking the same and exact value what is there in database columns..Even a single capital letter that i change is also not considered

Answer (score 0):

Like User016 said, I would also recommend using the IN Statement. It searchs for several searchterms, splitted by a `,`.

You can find the Doc there:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in